# Как выровнять адаптивно и кроссбраузерно кнопку по центру фона?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5, iframe

Приветствую всех! Как выровнять адаптивно и кроссбраузерно кнопку по центру по середине изображения, чтобы при клике на ней продолжало проигрываться видео?

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $(this).html('<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nDUSAJdNQxk?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
});
```

```css
.video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
button {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <video poster="http://www.fragranceoilexpress.com/files/2194097/store/55.jpg">
    <source src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nDUSAJdNQxk?rel=0&autoplay=1">
      <object>
        <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nDUSAJdNQxk?rel=0&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="false" allowscriptaccess="always" />
      </object>
      <p>Формат не поддерживается</p>
  </video>
  <button>Запустить видео</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

[вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/669zdgrj/3/) заработало. только не знаю как кнопку спозиционировать правильно на всех разрешения - может быть подскажет кто?

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('.video-wrapper').html('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nDUSAJdNQxk?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
});
```

```css
.video-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
button {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  background: transparent;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div class="video-wrapper">
  <video poster="http://www.fragranceoilexpress.com/files/2194097/store/55.jpg">
    <source src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nDUSAJdNQxk?rel=0&autoplay=1">
      <object>
        <embed src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nDUSAJdNQxk?rel=0&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="false" allowscriptaccess="always" />
      </object>
      <p>Формат не поддерживается</p>
  </video>
  <button>Запустить видео</button>
</div>
```